# Unable to transfer/copy local textfiles into HDFS/Hadoop

Tags: macos, hadoop

I use a Mac book pro, and I am running my Hadoop on docker. When I tried to copy/ transfer .txt files into HDFS, it kept telling me that "No such file or directory", but the file does exist, and I can access to it when I am not using localhost at Hadoop.

I have tried -put, and it says the something.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`hduser@localhost` looks like you've exec'd into the container, which has a different filesystem than your Mac. Therefore, the file would not be at that specific location unless you have ran your container with `-v /Users:/Users`, which should be avoided and you should rather mount your Downloads folder, at the very least

For example

```
docker run --ti -v $HOME/Downloads/:/mnt/Downloads hdfs-client 
hdfs -mkdir /hn958-hw1
hdfs -put /mnt/Downloads/txtfile.txt /hn958-hw1
```